# Handle Blob in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, blob

Good afternoon, everyone.

I am in possession of a database with a column "value" and would like to see the content. In this one there is only "blob". I would like to see the content of the column.

I tried this command:

```
SELECT quote(value) FROM products_id
```

From this I get a long string. You can find it here:
https://pastebin.com/WtNycvH3

I have already tried to decode this, but without success.

The solutions on the internet couldn't help me either.

I hope someone can help me.

Have a good day

Comment: `quote()` on a blob returns a blob literal. If you want the raw bytes to pass on to something else, don't use that function.

Comment: Hello. 
thank you for your answer.
How else can i read the data so that it is displayed as an array? if i make SELECT value FROM products_id, i get only "blob

Comment: That depends entirely on whatever language you're using to work with the values stored in the database.

Comment: Thank you,
I have now checked the code further and found this file. (Was decompiled by me): https://pastebin.com/u1RCz3tP

But it is not possible for me to write a function that reads the code the same way... it seems to me as if a json comes out at the end.